# leer $_session php en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

hola saben que estoy haciendo un login y no se mucho como restringir el acceso via contruyendo url pero lei algo de sesiones en php y lo estoy intentando pero estoy algo perdido y tengo algo asi como mi pagina login que llama mediante una peticion ajax un archivo intermedio llamado call_login y este me retorna un valor true o false esto lo uso solo para ver si se hizo todo correcto y ese call_login le pasa mi usuaio y contraseña a leer.php que en este retorno un true o false dependiendo si encontro ese usuario o no . Se que debo capturar el usuario con que inicia sesion y eso lo hago en el login luego que me retorne todo bien de leer y eso y lo hago asi:

```
<script>   $('#log').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = $("#user-login").val();

    var parametros = {
    'user'     : user, 
    'pass'     : $("#pass-login").val(),
                  }

    $.ajax({
      data: parametros,
      url: 'php/php-pdo/call_login.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(d){
        console.log(d);
        if (d == true) {
          console.log("Acceso concedido");
          // console.log(user);
          <?php $_SESSION['username'] = $user; ?> //Si se loguea correctamente creamos sesion con nombre de el usuario
          window.location.href = "index.php"; 
        } else {
          console.log("Acceso denegado");
        }
      },
      error:function(e){
        console.log(e);

      }


    })

  })

</script>
```

mi duda es como capturo el nombre de mi usuario que inicia la sesion esta lnea es la que me genera el error $_SESSION['username'] = $user; y lo otro luego de que eso me deje dar error que mas hago ? :O se que debo iniciar algo asi como la sesion de nuevo en la pagina que estoy restringiendo con session_start() y luego verificar que no sea vacia pero no estoy seguro jeje

Comment: Te sugiero crear la variable sesión en el fichero `call_login.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta línea `<?php $_SESSION['username'] = $user; ?>` debes colocarla en tu php en el archivo que te dice si el usuario existe o no, cabe aclarar que antes de la línea en mención debes colocar `session_start();` y cualquier archivo que tu quieras que sea accesible solo para usuarios logueados debe tenerla y debes comparar con una condición, algo así:

Archivo que hace la lógica del login (php):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $user;
```

Archivo de vista exclusiva para usuarios logueados (php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('location: ubicacion.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
..........
```

Otro punto importante es que todos los archivos que quieras restringir deben tener extensión `.php`

Espero haber sido claro y espero que te sirva

Comment: gracias amigo jejejejej tenias razon, no sabia que $_SESSION era una variable global y lo que hice fue declararla al archivo entre el ajax que llama al archivo del medio y el que tiene la funcion de leer en la db y sin problemas y le agregue el codigo a mi pagina que queria restringir tal cual me dijiste basicamente sabia que hacer pero no donde hacerlo ejejej por cierto despues del mensaje como hago para que me retorne a mi pagina de logueo hice esto pero no me funciono echo'<script language="javascript">
              location.href="index.php";
             </script>';

Comment: session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo ("Logueate primero");
        echo'<script language="javascript">
              location.href="index.php";
             </script>';
    }

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta añadiendo la función de php que hace la redirección al usuario en caso de que no esté logueado, solo cambias ubicación por la ruta de tu archivo login

Comment: muchas gracias amigo jejejejje me ayudaste un mundo